# Removing Last Item In Array, Deletes Whole Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I have an if statement inside a for loop which loops through the whole array and displays the elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < txtA.length; i++) {
    txtA[i].update();
    txtA[i].show();

    if (txtA[i].y == height) {
        txtA.pop();
        console.log(txtA.length);
    }
}
```

The if statement checks the elements height compared to the canvas and removes the element. The problem is that all the elements in the array are removed when the if statement equals true. HELP!

Comment: Can we also see the array you're working with?

Comment: Are you sure the array had more than one element to begin with?

Comment: The array holds multiple object constructor functions, with an x,y,letter, update() and show();

Comment: @Carcigenicate the array gets an element when a key is pressed, then the program tries to delete an element of the array when it hits the bottom. But it deletes all of the elements, which I can tell from the console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're doing a pop. Pop removes the last element of the array. If your first item hits the bottom then it's going to remove the last item in the array. It's going to loop over and keep removing the last item until it finally removes the first item that hit the bottom.

Use splice instead

`txtA.splice(i, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

**Your logic must be in error**, which is difficult to address without knowing the contents of the Array.

That being said, `Array.prototype.pop` is *not* responsible for the behavior you describe.  From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

> The pop method removes the last element from an array and returns that
>   value to the caller... If you call pop() on an empty array, it returns
>   undefined.

I.e. pop either removes the last element from the Array or (in the case of an empty Array) does nothing and returns undefined; it never actually deletes the Array.  If it is *clearing* the Array, then it must be removing one element at a time, popping one element from the end of the Array on each iteration.